# Matrix square rooting using SVD

Tags: matrices, svd

This the first time I deal with the matrix square rooting, there are many types of matrix decomposition techniques that factorize the matrix **P** into a  form  $P=SS^T$. For example, the Cholesky decomposition, the eigenvector decomposition or the singular value decomposition (**SVD**). I read that the most of mathematicians prefer to apply **SVD**, since it is the most robust algorithm to factorize a matrix especially when the matrix becomes nearly singular.

The first document I read it was a Phd thesis: The **SVD** of $P=UDU^T$, where **U** is matrix containing eigenvectors and **D** is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. The square-root of  the matrix x is then given by $S=U\sqrt{D}U^T$

I want to know more about matrix square rooting using SVD: explanations and proofs, can someone give me some references or even if you can explain how it works by numerical examples in the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My question here might help you a little: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820169/a-is-a-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-it-has-square-root-using-svd